# Pub command is not found after installing dart-sdk

Tags: ubuntu, path, dart

I want to write a command line application on my Ubuntu machine but I encountered a problem when I was installing the dart sdk of dart 2 on linux mint 19.

After the installation I can't run the pub command from the terminal.
I always get this error:

```
   Command 'pub' not found, did you mean:

  command 'puf' from deb puf
  command 'pdb' from deb python
  command 'publ' from deb atfs
  command 'pua' from deb pglistener
  command 'dub' from deb dub
  command 'pcb' from deb pcb-gtk
  command 'pcb' from deb pcb-lesstif
  command 'pudb' from deb python-pudb

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I already tried some path settings from the internet but none of them work or only temporarily.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In window 10, after installing flutter, dart sdk is in D:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's important to ensure that the dart SDK is in the PATH. You can easily test it by trying to use `pub` or `dart`.

One way to ensure it's in the PATH is by creating a .bashrc file in your user's folder.

Then add the following:

`PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dart/installation/bin/folder
export PATH`

Answer (score 61):

As someone mentioned in a comment to an (outdated) answer, the nowadays (due to Dart being supplied / integrated with / in Flutter now) suggested correct use of pub is to be called via the flutter command:

```
`flutter pub`
```

ie. to use gRPC / protobufs v3 w/ Dart / Flutter:

```
`flutter pub global activate protoc_plugin`
```

Comment: In my case, it worked calling via the dart command: 'dart pub'.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer right now

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes when you install `dart`, you may also have a problem where the `dart` command works but the `pub` command does not work, this is because `dart` is only present in the /usr/bin, to solve this simply make a symlink and to add pub command to this `/usr/bin` directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub /usr/bin/pub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Use:
flutter pub
Instead of:
pub
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34475

Answer (score 16):

`dart pub` in your command line works as well now.

Answer (score 4):

Open `~/.profile` and add dart installation folder into the end

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, on windows, dart-sdk was located at `C:\tools\dart-sdk` and pub command was not found even after adding `C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin` to `PATH` because pub was located at `C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat` as a batch file.

So I have to do `pub.bat` every time from the cli or alias can also be configured pointing pub to pub.bat.

Answer (score 1):

Open Your command line or terminal and locate or open this path:
*C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin*

Press enter and input your command line

**Mine:**

```
pub global activate openid_client
```

It will download necessary things.

It may likely show you this

**
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.**

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same, in my case after installing Dart neither `dart --version or pub --version` where running so for that what I have done to make it running is that I went into that `dart-sdk\bin` and manually executed them by clicking each .bat and .exe as mine was Windows and then running `dart --version or pub --version` started giving results.

I think so this problem is for Windows Systems because those 2 commands worked fine after installing Dart in Mac and Linux. So whatever maybe the OS, just try manually executing executable by double-clicking and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your flutter doctor is showing no error in the terminal , them you may try using 'flutter run lib/main.dart'. That helped me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?